# How can I show links for custom posts group by taxonomy current term and sub-term?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I tried to display post with links by sub term and group thouse posts and sub terms by parent terms.
For example:

Parent term 1

- Parent term 1

  Term 1

  - Post1
  - Post2
  - Post3

  Term 2

  - Post4
  - Post5
- Parent term 2

  Term 3

  - Post6
  - Post7

Instead of this I receive:

- Term 1

  - Post1
  - Post2
  - Post3
  - Post4
  - Post5
  - Post6
  - Post7

  Term 2

  - Post1
  - Post2
  - Post3
  - Post4
  - Post5
  - Post6
  - Post7

  Term 3...

Here is my current code:

```
$all_terms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'course-category', 'hide_empty' => 1 ] );
if (!$all_terms){
    $Content = '<h2>no terms</h2>';;
    
}
foreach (  $all_terms as $term ) { // external
    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'course'
        
        
    ]);
    if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) continue;
    $Content .= '<h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
    $Content .= "<div>";
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {// internal
        $query->the_post();
        $Content .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        
       
    }
    $Content .= "</div>";
```

I don't realy understand how to use get_terms(), and maybe, get_term_children() for deal with this.

Help me please to solve this ...
I'll be grateful for any advice you can share.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't realy understand how to use get_terms(), and maybe, get_term_children() for deal with this.

I believe you're missing 3 important pieces of information:

- terms that have no parent have a parent ID of `0`
- you can ignore `get_term_children`, just use the `parent` parameter of `get_terms`
- for this to work more than one or two levels deep you will need to put this in a recursive function or you'll just end up with tonnes of nested loops

`get_terms` takes the same arguments as `WP_Term_Query`, I strongly recommend reading through the available arguments on the official documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

Likewise, all of this would have been explained with examples in the comments for the official `get_terms` documentation page:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/